# Which is a larger performance drain: quantity of vertices in one draw call, or quantity of calls?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am quickly finding that one of the organisational considerations you must make when preparing rendering in OpenGL is the type of topography and the arrangement of vertices.

Now there are some interesting methods out there for organising vertices into very long arrays, with nice uses of interleaved arrays, indexes, etc, so that you can pour a lot of geometry into one OpenGL call.

But it's much easier in some cases to simply iterate and perform multiple calls with smaller vertex arrays.

While I agree with the notion that premature optimization is somewhat wasteful, just how important of a consideration should it be to minimize OpenGL calls, especially if multiple calls would actually involve far fewer vertexes per call?

I can see that this is one of those decisions that is important early in the development process, since it forms a lot of the structure of how vertexes get created and organized.

Comment: To me your question gets confusing at some point. At some places you are kind of implying that fewer calls is better regarding performance. And you probably know the answer to your question in the title. The analysis about how far you should go with optimizing 'number of calls' over smaller calls with fewer vertices and simplicity, and when to optimize providing it affects a good part of your code structure seems to be a far more interesting question. Even though its quite implementation-dependent, i'd love to hear some expert thoughts about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an overhead for each command you send down to the GPU. By batching the vertices you minimize that overhead and also allows the driver to make small optimizations in you data before sending it to the hardware. It can make quite a difference and is the reason the glBegin and glEnd was completely removed from newer iterations of OpenGL.

You should try to avoid making many driver states changes and many drawing calls.

**EDIT**: Consider using degenerated vertices in you triangle strips (also helps in minimizing the number of vertices processed) so that you can just use one drawing call and render all your topology (unless you need to change some driver state between parts of the topology).

Comment: Aside degenerate vertices (well actually edges) with newer versions of OpenGL there's also the possibility to specify a special primitive restart index. So whenever that index is encountered in a index array a new primitive is started. This is usefull especially in situation where stips are separated by a gap. However using strips doesn't gain so much these days. GPUs have been optimized for indexed triangles (not strips) and process them the best.

Comment: I bet you that is not true for mobile GPUs, but I haven't tested it myself though. Just pointing out it is something to consider. It's true that for desktop GPUs everything is at least an order of magnitude different and they have more die space for optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a balance for your specific needs. But the thing is that there're many variables in the equation. And there's no simple solution (like "*always make scene as one big single batch!*"). **TraxNet** gave you a good advice though - always try to minimize api calls(whether drawing or state changes). But it hasn't to be just a few calls. On modern PC it could be thousands per frame, not so modern mobile phone, maybe, just a few hundred.
Also **TraxNet** mentioned degenerate triangles(helping form strips) - though they're still triangles(kinda add to 'total' triangle count rendered) - they cost almost nothing still helping to minimize amount of draw calls.